# Air line rotary fitting?

Tags: compressor

i'm trying to attach my compressor to a filter/regulator mounted on the wall with a short lead like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA9CQ.jpg)

The problem is that the threaded ends on the hose are fixed to the hose.  So I can't thread them in to something at each end without twisting the hose.  Many of the longer hoses have a fitting on the end that swivels, but not the short ones I've seen.

It seems there must be some kind of swivel union sort of  fitting to do this, but my google-fu is failing me and haven't found it at local hardware stores.  What's this called?

I know I could do it with a quick disconnect - just seems I should be able to screw it together.

Comment: Milton 1/4" NPT Swivel Hose Fitting (S-659). But question like this usually get closed fast, as "shopping" questions are out of the SE mandate.